# Turn a sortable list into a query and retrieve it and display it again

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here I have an example of me creating a string using [JQuery UI sortable event](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) I wanted to take multiple string like this

> $string: item[]=4&item[]=1&item[]=2

And call back a select one to present on a page. I am planning on storing these $string 's in a MySQL table.

Basically how would I receive said $string and and use it to display something in a particular order

Here's a JSfiddle to show you what stage I'm at.

https://jsfiddle.net/mjfncugx/

---

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
        <li id="item_1">test1</li>
        <li id="item_2">test2</li>
        <li id="item_3">test3</li>
        <li id="item_4">test4</li>
        <li id="item_5">test5</li>
      </ul>
      Query String: <span></span>
```

JQuery UI

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
      $('span').text(data);
      /*$.ajax({
          data: oData,
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/your/url/here'
      });*/
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So now you need to write some PHP code to accept that data and query a database, and send some data back to the javascript. That as a question is **to broad**. When you have written the PHP code, if you get issues with it come back and ask a question about that.

Comment: Serialize is returning data ready for a get request. Therefor using ajax to send a get request to a php page that can then process the get data and send it to the db is your easiest option.

Comment: I wasn't very specific about that, what I really was asking is how would I select a particular $string from the database and recreate it using PHP to present in HTML. how would I do this?

Comment: Well first you read the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) then you take some good tips on good ways to do things [from lets say here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) But here at SO **we do not write code for you**

Comment: Okay fair enough :), but how would I take $string and make a html ordered list from it? Saying I have item[]=4&item[]=1&item[]=2 how would I use that to order a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saving in Db just use this

```
str_replace('[]=', '_', 'item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5');
```

AFter inserting..

I am assuming that `$data = item_2&item_1&item_3&item_4&item_5;` which is coming from DB.

```
<?php
$data = !empty($data) ? explode('&', $data) : '';
?>


<ul id="sortable">
<?php
    if(!is_array($data))
    {
?>
    <li id="item_1">test1</li>
    <li id="item_2">test2</li>
    <li id="item_3">test3</li>
    <li id="item_4">test4</li>
    <li id="item_5">test5</li>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        foreach($data as $data_row)
        {
            ?>
            <li id="<?= $data_row ?>"><?= str_replace('_', '', $data_row); ?></li>
            <?php
        }
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

There might be some syntax error if so please correct it.